# Encryption in C# and decryption in Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography

I am doing Encryption in C# for windows phone 8.1 app and I need to decrypt it using java.
Here is my Encryption code

```
   public static String encrypt(String plaintext, KeyParameter keyParam)
    {
        byte[] ivData = new byte[AES_NIVBITS / 8];
        Random r = new Random();

        r.NextBytes(ivData);


        IBlockCipherPadding padding = new Pkcs7Padding();
         BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesEngine()), padding);


        ICipherParameters param = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, ivData); 
        cipher.Reset();
        cipher.Init(true, param);

        byte[] bytesDec = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(plaintext); 


        byte[] bytesEnc = null;

        int buflen = cipher.GetOutputSize(bytesDec.Length);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("enc length " + buflen);
        bytesEnc = new byte[buflen];
        int nBytesEnc = cipher.ProcessBytes(bytesDec, 0, bytesDec.Length, bytesEnc, 0);
        nBytesEnc += cipher.DoFinal(bytesEnc, nBytesEnc);

        if (nBytesEnc != bytesEnc.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected behaviour : getOutputSize value incorrect");
        }

        byte[] bytesAll = new byte[ivData.Length + bytesEnc.Length];
        Array.Copy(ivData, 0, bytesAll, 0, ivData.Length);
        Array.Copy(bytesEnc, 0, bytesAll, ivData.Length, bytesEnc.Length);

        byte[] bytesAllb64 = Base64.Encode(bytesAll);
        return Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytesAllb64, 0, bytesAllb64.Length);


    }
```

And this is the java code for decryption

```
public static String decodeBase64Aes(String encodedciphertext, KeyParameter keyParam) throws Exception 
{
    byte[] bytesEnc = Base64.decode(encodedciphertext.getBytes(ISO8859));

    int nIvBytes = AES_NIVBITS / 8;
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[nIvBytes];
    System.arraycopy(bytesEnc, 0, ivBytes, 0, nIvBytes);

    CipherParameters params = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, ivBytes);
    BlockCipherPadding padding = new PKCS7Padding();
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()), padding);

    cipher.reset();
    cipher.init(false, params); 

    byte[] bytesDec = null;

    int buflen = cipher.getOutputSize(bytesEnc.length - nIvBytes);
    byte[] workingBuffer = new byte[buflen];
    int len = cipher.processBytes(bytesEnc, nIvBytes, bytesEnc.length - nIvBytes, workingBuffer, 0);
    len += cipher.doFinal(workingBuffer, len);

    bytesDec = new byte[len];
    System.arraycopy(workingBuffer, 0, bytesDec, 0, len);

    return new String(bytesDec, ISO8859);
}
```

When I am encrypting it it's working fine but when I test decryption using the encrypted text I got and key, it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption
```

I can only change the c# part. Any help would be highly appreciated???

```
Key  -> 8fe3f8b34e87744c175aae43cc52ee13
'Hello World' -> Nb90n51LqK13LzpalV7qTs7YJqe9m+Ni9uA/U7tU06Y=
```

The Exception Comes on line

```
 len += cipher.doFinal(workingBuffer, len);
```

When I encrypt "Hello World" from java using the same key from the encryption method I have on my server I get

```
uWMz8ZIPh+3jnGtwxpuyK9Qht7BJV4RQ/Iet9JeTrTk=
```

EDIT ------

Updated to working code.

Comment: What Base64 classes do you use exactly?

Comment: I am using bouncycastle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base 64 does not give same length as the original one and that's why I was gettting that error. I have updated the code with the correct one.